# Debian VirtualBox auto mount fails on startup but works after login: mounting failed with the error: No such device

Tags: debian, mount, virtualbox, automounting

I have a VirtualBox Debianx64 system installed and I was trying to share a host folder to it. Following a tutorial, I came to a mount command:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 [Virtual Box share name here] [path where to mount]
```

That works perfectly. I can edit the files and stuff...

The `uid` and `gid` reffers to the information you get by typing:

```
[Your Name]@debianvirtualbox:~$ id -u [Your Name]
1000
[Your Name]@debianvirtualbox:~$ id -g [Your Name]
1000
```

Of course it really sucks to run this every time, so I wanted to automount it. According to some tips, this could be done by adding command to `/etc/rc.local`, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
# By default this script does nothing.
mount -t vboxsf -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 share /home/[Your Name]/share
exit 0
```

Now when I restarted system, nothing was mounted. I found [this answer that helped me to log the error output of my `/etc/rc.local`](https://askubuntu.com/a/434276/128031), which is:

```
+ mount -t vboxsf -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 share /home/[Your Name]/share
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device
```

I was thinking that maybe the mounting is happening too soon... Could I try to auto-mount it during login phase?

*From comments:*

I added `lsmod|grep -i vbox >&2` *before* the mount command resulting in this output:

```
+ grep -i vbox
+ lsmod
vboxvideo              12437  0 
drm                   249955  2 vboxvideo
vboxguest             213028  0
```

Comment: I don't have a configuration to test this, but could you add a line to your rc.local `lsmod|grep -i vbox >&2` and tell us the output? Your rc.local may be running before the guest additions have loaded/probed the required kernel drivers.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Contrary to my expectations, it seems at least some of the virtual items are loaded already - see the updated question.

Comment: Which version of debian are you running?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The new Jessie release, I think it's number 8. I'll add detailed info about version tomorrow when I'm at work.

Answer (score 1):

Running Debian 8.2 I had the same problem, fixed it by adding `vboxsf` to `/etc/modules` (from [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/365690)).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [VBox Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and [VirtualBox Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) which will provide extra support for certain devices.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the OS running rc.local too fast, before the service is actually loaded. Add a sleep 10 in the script line.

sleep 10 && mount -t vboxsf -o rw,uid=33,gid=33 www /var/www/html/