# Run script as admin (prompt for password) from xfce GUI

Tags: bash, mount, sudo, xfce

I have a mount script I need to run as admin. Since [nobody knows how to run it automatically](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/231849/27719), I want to at least reduce the pain of manual start. The script has one line:

```
sudo mount ... more params
```

When I select execute, nothing happens:

[image: image description]

I also tried [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28796/27719), no effect. If I run the script from terminal, everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gksudo` which is a GTK+ frontend for su/sudo.

`sudo` asks for the password on the command line, and `gksudo` pops up a dialog box for it.

Relevant [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gksudo)

Comment: I replaced `sudo` with `gksudo` in my script and I still observe nothing. Definitely not a dialog window.

Comment: Well, that's strange. Open a terminal window, type `gksudo whoami` and tell us what happens. If you haven't configured your user otherwise, a GUI prompt asking your password should pop up.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a `sudo` rule such that either all users, some specific users, and/or all members of a particular group can run the script without a password.  e.g. in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Cmnd_Alias MYSCRIPT = /usr/local/sbin/mountscript.sh
...
...
cas ALL = NOPASSWD: MYSCRIPT
%admin ALL = NOPASSWD: MYSCRIPT
```

That allows user `cas` and all members of group `admin` to run `/usr/local/sbin/mountscript.sh` as root without needing to enter a password.

`mountscript.sh` should be extremely simple.  It would be best if it took no arguments and no input at all from the user, and just performed a fixed set of operations (e.g. mount the filesystem in a particular location and then exit)

If required, you could also have an `unmountscript.sh` set up in sudo in the same way... just add `/usr/local/sbin/unmountscript.sh` to the end of the `Cmnd_Alias` definition line.

Finally, your icon on the desktop would either:

1. run `sudo /usr/local/sbin/mountscript.sh`
   or
2. run a wrapper shell script which did nothing except `sudo /usr/local/sbin/mountscript.sh`

in both cases, all scripts mentioned should be mdae executable with `chmod`